# Trouble Calculating Time Difference in Php5

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli, timer, timezone

I am creating a Php application of exam where i want to stop exam in 1 hour

I send test start time and end time in database
code of inserting time in db

```
<?php  $date = date('h-i-sa');
      $date1 = date('h-i-sa',strtotime('+5 min'));
      $sql = "insert into timer(name,start_time,end_time) values('$name','$date','$date1')"; ?>
```

now i fatch this time by fatch query

```
<?php $sel = "select * from timer where id=28"; 
$ex1=$conn->query($sel);
$r=$ex1->fetch_object(); ?>
```

Now I got
 exam start time  = `<?php $s_time = echo $r->start_time; ?>` 
 Exam end time = `<?php $e_time = echo $r->end_time; ?>` 
and 
Latest Time = `<?php
                   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
                   $l_time = echo date('h-i-sa');
               ?>`
Now i need difference between End time & Latest time means  $l_time & $e_time

i wrote following code , but its not working

```
<?php
    if($l_time == $e_time)
    {
         echo 'time over';
         echo "<script>alert('time over'); </script>";
         return 'index.php';
    }
?>
```

[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX1XN.png)

[Learn Yii Framework here](http://www.facebook.com/WebDeveloperSahajArora)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($l_time <= $e_time)
{
      alert('time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is wrong. Moving time is never (or very rarely) equal while running a script. Your if statement should be one of the following. I can't tell which one is correct because your variable naming scheme is hard to read.

```
if($l_time >= $e_time)

// or

if($l_time <= $e_time)
```

Comment: l_time means latest (Present) time

Comment: e_time = end _time

Comment: but i got alert , when i reload , how can i got alert , without refresh / reload by ajax or jquery ?